# Visual Studio Shortcut for Automatically Creating Constructors from an Inherited Class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Say I am inheriting from a class with several "overloaded" constructors.

By any chance is there a short cut in Visual Studio which writes the constructors in the derived class with the same signatures as in the default class for me, with boilerplate code which calls MyBase.New(...) and plugs in the arguments for me?

EDIT:  As far as I can find there is no such shortcut built-in, however there is one in resharper as suggested by Raymond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about a shortcut in a standard Visual Studio installation, but if you install the excellent Resharper plugin from jetBrains, it is Alt-Insert, C. I don't develop without it.

Comment: A link to the plugin would have been excellent: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/